# MongoDB - duplicate documents removal

Tags: mongodb, duplicates

**Context**: I have a MongoDB database with some duplicated documents.

**Problem**: I want to remove all duplicated documents. *(For each duplicated document, I only want to save one, which can be arbitrarily chosen.)*

**Minimal illustrative example**:

The documents all have the following fields (*there are also other fields, but those are of no relevance here*):

```
{
    "_id": {"$oid":"..."},
    "name": "string",
    "user": {"$oid":"..."},
}
```

**Duplicated documents**: A document is considered duplicated if there are ***two or more*** documents with the **same "*name*" and "*user*"** (*i.e. the document id is of no relevance here*).

How can I remove the duplicated documents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**:
Since mongoDB version 4.2, one option is to use `$group` and `$merge` In order to move all unique documents to a new collection:

```
removeList = db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {name: "$name", user: "$user"},
      doc: {$first: "$$ROOT"}
    }
  },
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$doc"}},
  {$merge: {into: "newCollection"}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Tb6hY3BRlFp)

For older version, you do the same using `$out`.

Another option is to get a list of all documents to remove and remove them with another query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {name: "$name", user: "$user"},
      doc: {$first: "$$ROOT"},
      remove: {$push: "$_id"}
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      remove: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$remove",
          cond: {$ne: ["$$this", "$doc._id"]}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {$group: {_id: 0, remove: { $push: "$remove"}}},
  {$set: { _id: "$$REMOVE",
     remove: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$remove",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {$concatArrays: ["$$value", "$$this"]}
        }
      }
    }
  }
])

db.collection.deleteMany({_id: {$in: removeList}})
```

Comment: When I run this under aggregations in Atlas, it does not seem to have an effect on the number of documents in the collection. But I know for a fact that there are duplicates. Any idé why that my be? (I have version 5.0.9 of MongoDb.)

Comment: I edited the answer. If it is important to use the existing collection I can think of a solution for this

Comment: Btw, what do you mean by "If it is important to use the existing collection"?

Comment: For the edited answer, I first get "'DeprecationWarning: Collection.remove() is deprecated. Use deleteOne, deleteMany, findOneAndDelete, or bulkWrite.'". I also get "BSONError: cyclic dependency detected", which I still get when replacing "remove" by "deleteMany".

Comment: Do you run it as a different query?

Comment: I run it in the mongosh terminal in compass, as
removeList = db.collection.aggregate([...])
and then 
db.collection.remove({_id: {$in: removeList}})

Comment: Try running `db.collection.aggregate([...])` only. Copy the results. Run `db.collection.deleteMany({_id: {$in: <results>}})`

Comment: How do I copy the results?

Comment: I'm not familiar with compass, but maybe ctrl + C or right click